# nuxt3 vee-validate errors always"not valid"

Tags: validation, nuxt.js, vee-validate

I have added vee-validate v4 to Nuxt3 project . Validation works fine except that it does not show which type of rule failed.. Always it show "field-name is not valid" . As per documentation, it should tell more like " email is required" or "email format is wrong" and so on..

```
  <VForm>
      <VField name="email" rules="required|email" v-slot="{ field, errors, meta }">
        <input v-bind="field" type="text" />

        {{ errors }}
      </VField>
    </VForm>
```

Any one knows what is the issue and or has an idea ?

thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to define the error messages. For example:

```js
import { defineRule, Form as VeeForm, Field, ErrorMessage, configure  } from 'vee-validate';
import { required, email, min } from '@vee-validate/rules';
import { localize, setLocale } from '@vee-validate/i18n';
import es from '@vee-validate/i18n/dist/locale/es.json';
import en from '@vee-validate/i18n/dist/locale/en.json';

// Define rules
defineRule('required', required);
defineRule('email', email);
defineRule('min', min);

// Set locale
localize({ es });
setLocale('es');

// Configure localized error messages
configure({
    generateMessage: localize({
        es: {
            messages: es.messages,
        },
        en: {
            messages: en.messages,
        },
    }),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to install the language package and add the configuration for it as you like

[Localization (i18n)](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/i18n/#using-vee-validatei18n)

I got the answer from the creator of the package

[Why I am getting all errors as "is not valid" ? #3999](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/i18n/#using-vee-validatei18n)